# Why was my question migrated to English Language Learners?

Tags: discussion, migration

Before I asked my question I thought [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/102399/what-is-the-difference-between-self-evident-and-self-explanatory) should be posted in [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) but it was migrated to https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Wouldn't it be better in UX than English Language Learners?

Comment: You are asking about the words and what they mean. This is not a question about UX. That the words appear in a UX book doesn't make the question a UX question.

Comment: This question probably shouldn't be on Stack Exchange Meta. I think [meta.ux.se] would be a better place for it, or [meta.ell.se] at a stretch, although it's better that it isn't asked using the Q&A system (i.e. should be asked in the relevant chatroom).

Comment: oh..I have no idea there exists Meta for the UX and English Learner.

Comment: BTW. Wouldn't it be better to add an automatic question migration to specific Meta for the newly created question here ? Suggest to add an area tags in Meta. Like `Language`, `UX`, `Overflow` etc

Comment: @Joe.wang every site has its own meta on which you should ask questions relating to that particular site. There is a link to the current site that you are browsing's meta underneath "current community" if you click the "StackExchange" dropdown in the top bar.

Comment: @Cai Got it . Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is basically - what is the difference between the phrases "self-evident" and "self-explanatory".

This is not a UX question.

It is an English question.

That's why it got migrated.

---

That these words appeared in a UX book doesn't make the question relevant to UX.

Suppose these were in a science fiction novel or a cooking book? Would you ask on those sites instead of the English one?

Comment: em..It makes sense. Thanks.